# How to "unwrap" regexp helpers like [:digit:] in str_count?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Assuming the following data, I want to count the unique characters per row.

```
test <- data.frame(oe = c("A-1", "111", "-", "Sie befassen sich intensiv damit"))
```

So I thought I'm using the `[:graph:]` helper to capture letters, numbers and punctuation. However, it gives the wrong results, see below:

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>%
  mutate(unique_chars_correct = sapply(tolower(oe), function(x) sum(str_count(x, c(letters, 0:9, "-")) > 0)),
         unique_chars_wrong   = sapply(tolower(oe), function(x) sum(str_count(x, "[:graph:]") > 0)))
```

which gives:

```
                                oe unique_chars_correct unique_chars_wrong
1                           A-1\\.                    3                  1
2                              111                    1                  1
3                                -                    1                  1
4 Sie befassen sich intensiv damit                   13                  1
```

I assume, using `[:graph:]` kind of checks if any of the chars satisfies being part of `[:graph:]`, but want to do is to check every element that is part of `[:graph:]`.

Comment: Yes, the unique characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[:graph:]` gives the total count and it is not differentiating the `unique` characters

```
> str_count(test$oe, "[:graph:]")
[1] 3 3 1
```

Thus, when we convert to a logical (`> 0`) and take the `sum` it returns just 1

and it doesn't differentiate between numbers/letters/punct.

---

If we need to get the expected

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(c("[:alpha:]", "[:digit:]", "[:punct:]"), 
        function(x) str_count(tolower(test$oe), x) >0) )
[1] 3 1 1
```

---

Or may split and then use `[:graph:]` on the `unique` values

```
sapply(strsplit(tolower(test$oe), ""), function(x)
      sum(str_count(unique(x), "[:graph:]") > 0))
[1] 3 1 1
```

Comment: ok, maybe my example is bad and maybe it is related to special characters, but e.g. on my real world data set (containing 133k rows), your results (and my old one just gives me values of 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes, I will update my example. Problem is, I do not yet understand the pattern when it works and when not, hence it's not easy to find a reproducible example. But I will update my post above.

Comment: My bad, your solution actually works, I had to refresh my data/R Session for whatever reason. The only adjustment I made is to wrap a `tolower` into the strsplit function, because I doN#t care about upper/lowercase.

Comment: Please note my edited solution, which takes care of the issues mentioned/hinted at.

Answer (score 2):

You can use backreference and lookaround for this:

Data:

```
test <- data.frame(oe = c("A-1", "111", "-", "Abaa", "B cbb b"))
```

**EDITED** Solution: (also accounts for whitespace, which is **not** counted, as well as upper- and lower-case distinctions, which are disregarded=

```
library(stringr)
str_count(test$oe, "(?i)([^\\s])(?!.*\\1)")
[1] 3 1 1 2 2
```

How this works:

- `(?i)`: case-**i**nsensitive match
- `([^\\s])`: a capture group matching any character that is not a whitespace char
- `(?!`: the start of a negative lookahead, preventing the matching and, hence, inclusion in the `str_count` operation of what follows:
- `.*`: any character occurring zero or more times
- `\\1`: backreference recalling the exact match of the capturing group `(.)`and thus, in the context of the negative lookahead, effectively preventing the matching and counting of any repetitions of it
- `)`: end of negative lookahead

**EDIT**:

alternatively you can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  mutate(
    # set to lower-case and remove whitespace:
    oe = tolower(gsub("\\s", "", oe)),
    # split the strings into separate chars:
    oe_splt = str_split(oe, ""),
    # count unique chars:
    count_unq = lengths(sapply(oe_splt, function(x) unique(x))))
```

Comment: Your solution (I tested the dplyr one runs fast), but it gives a somewhat wrong result, e.g. this string "Sie befassen sich intensiv damit", gives 15 in your solution whereas it returns 13 in akrun's solution (and 13 would be correct IMO).

Comment: If you only count letters but do not count whitespace and do not distinguish between lower and upper case, 13 may be correct